# Is it possible to change the iPhone orientation animation in my app

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I have implemented the method `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`, and my iPhone app nicely `animates` the `orientation` movement when I switch between `landscape` and `portrait`.

My question is: is it possible to have a different type of `animation`? Are there other built in `animations` that I could use for that `transition`? Or could I tamper with it myself? Can anyone show me example of code to change the `animation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely it's possible. Here's a custom animation that I did to move several views around to different places:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation 
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; {
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];

        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
            toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            [myImage setCenter:CGPointMake(384.0,170.0)];
            [firstLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(235.0,358.0)];
            [secondLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(519.0,358.0)];
            [button0 setCenter:CGPointMake(164.0,508.0)];
            [button1 setCenter:CGPointMake(384.0,508.0)];
            [button2 setCenter:CGPointMake(604.0,508.0)];
            [button3 setCenter:CGPointMake(274.0,666.0)];
            [button4 setCenter:CGPointMake(494.0,666.0)];
            [button5 setCenter:CGPointMake(164.0,824.0)];
            [button6 setCenter:CGPointMake(384.0,824.0)];
            [button7 setCenter:CGPointMake(604.0,824.0)];
            [button8 setCenter:CGPointMake(164.0,954.0)];
            [button9 setCenter:CGPointMake(604.0,954.0)];       
        } else {
            [myImage setCenter:CGPointMake(350.0,173.0)];
            [firstLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(844.0,66.0)];
            [secondLabel setCenter:CGPointMake(844.0,114.0)];
            [button0 setCenter:CGPointMake(140.0,450.0)];
            [button1 setCenter:CGPointMake(388.0,450.0)];
            [button2 setCenter:CGPointMake(636.0,450.0)];
            [button3 setCenter:CGPointMake(884.0,450.0)];
            [button4 setCenter:CGPointMake(140.0,638.0)];
            [button5 setCenter:CGPointMake(388.0,638.0)];
            [button6 setCenter:CGPointMake(636.0,638.0)];
            [button7 setCenter:CGPointMake(884.0,638.0)];
            [button8 setCenter:CGPointMake(844.0,190.0)];
            [button9 setCenter:CGPointMake(844.0,280.0)];       
        }   
    } [UIView commitAnimations];            
}
```

This worked great as each image flies across the screen to land in a new spot. You can use something like this to create all kinds of effects.